# How do we move a specific branch to a new repository and maintain the connection back?

Tags: mercurial

Here's what I'd like to do:

- We have a repository for our 5.X product.
- We have branches for 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, etc.
- We have 6.0 coming up.
- We want to create a whole new repository for 6.X.

However, here's the rub.  We want to be able to:

- Base that new 6.X repository on the very "far right" tip of the 5.x repository.

  - That is, the "5.last" branch
- Migrate/merge forward maintenance changes and other fixed we make to the 5.X branch from there to the 6.X repository.

In other words, we want to have two repositories that sort of act like one big one.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A Guide to Branching in Mercurial", mix of [Branching with Clones](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-clones) and [Branching with Named Branches](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-named-branches)

You'll use both methods

- Repo R5 with development branch V5
- Repo R6 with development branch V6

No matter how R6will be launched: clone and strip old changesets, export tip from R5 and adding it as first cset into R6. Only result have sense: R5 and R6 with different branchname of *mainline development*

"Foreign" repository must appear in path section and sync performed by pull|push with -b option, where BRANCHNAME in -b is the name of branch for *mainline development in foreign repo*

Merge branches after pu(ll|sh) and have fun

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible because a node cannot exist without it's ancestors. A changeset is nothing more than the differences from it's father. If you want Repo6 to receive changesets from Repo5 it must have the whole thing in it.